# What's the function of 'a' in the following sentences?

Tags: gramática

1. "Mientras Pepe jugaba a el baloncesto": el baloncesto has no life nor related to human beings, why put "a" in the sentence, why not say like "mientras Pepe jUgaba el baloncesto".
2. "Fue primero a la farmacia". What's the function of "a"? Why not use "en" en la farmacia?
3. "Por qué faltaste a clase" Why put "a" not "el" here?

Comment: > Mientras Pepe jugaba a el baloncesto.
It's not correct. A+el: al. The same goes for de+el: del.
> Mientras Pepe jugaba al baloncesto.
And 'El auto es de el vecino':
> El auto es del vecino.

Answer (score 7):

1. Unlike the English verb *to play*, the Spanish verb *jugar* is intransitive. Therefore, you need a preposition to introduce its complements. In this case, to introduce the game you are playing, you use the preposition *a*. Why is it transitive in one language and intransitive in the other? Well, that's just the way each language has evolved.
2. In Spanish, *fue* can be the past indefinite of either the verb *ser* or *ir*. This sentence can mean that he was the first person to arrive in the pharmacy (in this case, it would be the verb *ser*) or that he went to the pharmacy before going somewhere else (in this case, it would be the verb *ir*). As written in the example, the preposition *a* indicates the second case; the verb *ir* is a movement verb, so it uses the preposition *a* to indicate the destination of the movement. If you wanted to use the preposition *en*, you would probably write *Fue el primero en la farmacia*, and in this case *fue* would be the verb *ser* (he was the first to arrive at the pharmacy).
3. There is no way you can use *el* in this sentence, since *clase* is feminine. Anyway, the verb *faltar* is intransitive too, so you need a preposition to introduce its complements. In this case, you are using the fourth meaning of the word in the DRAE (*no acudir a una cita u obligación*), and the preposition used to introduce this appointment or obligation is *a*.

Take into account that different languages have different grammar rules. You just have to learn how each word works in each language you learn.

Answer (score 1):

The different *a*'s that you're asking about all have different reasons which shows just how versatile the preposition is.

1. The verb *jugar* (not *jagar*) takes the preposition *a*.  That's just the way it is.  It's the same reason you *cuidar **de*** or *tener **que***.  It's not the *a personal* that's used with animate direct objects, though.
2. The verb *ir* generally uses prepositions indicating movement or motion, hence *ir a* (go to).  While there's nothing strictly ungrammatically about *ir en*, in the example you give, *entrar* would work better.
3. *faltar **a** (algo)* is an expression summed up in one of the DRAE's definitions: "Dicho de una persona: No corresponder a lo que es, o no cumplir con lo que debe. *Faltó a la lealtad, a la nobleza*."

Answer (score 0):

1. "Mientras Pepe jugaba a el baloncesto" ¿What was Pepe playing? Al Baloncesto. `"a el"` contracts to `"al"` and you can remove it since `"Baloncesto"` is a proper noun. `"Pepe jugaba el Baloncesto"` doesn't sounds bad for me but I think is more proper say `"Pepe jugaba al baloncesto"` or `"Pepe jugaba Baloncesto"` I'd pick the last one.
2. "Fue primero a la farmacia" ¿Where did he go first? A la farmacia [Not a proper noun `"A la"` required]. ¿Where did he buy first? En la farmacia.
3. "Por qué faltaste a clase" The only way of putting `"el"` in there is talking about time. "por qué faltaste el Jueves/otro día/mes de mayo/". Clase is not a proper noun so needs `"a"` but you can also say `"a la clase"`.

Comment: *Baloncesto* is not a proper noun. And, even if it was, it would still require the preposition, since *jugar* is intransitive. *Pepe jugaba al Monopoly* or *Pepe jugaba a Monopoly*. *Pepe jugaba baloncesto* is an anglicism.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mientras Pepe jugaba a el baloncesto" , well I would never say "a el baloncesto" , but I suposse it is formal spanish from Spain.
2. "Fue primero a la farmacia". Here 'a' means to . I guess it is the same in english , in english you say " I went TO the pharmacy first " not 'IN THE PHARMARCY"
3. "Por qué faltaste a clase" , first of all clase is considered here as an 'event'. Faltar is the opposite of attending an event or going somewhere so just use the same structure , pay attention: No fui A la fiesta = falté A la fiesta , since that 'no fui' equals to 'falté' you use the same structure , so you use 'a'.